# How to Connect an Activex Event to a Slot in python

Tags: python, qt, activex

I have an ActiveX control in a QAxWidget class and I am trying to connect an Activex Event to a Slot in python

> void MoveComplete (int ID) [signal]

The documentation says

```
QObject::connect(object, SIGNAL(MoveComplete(int)), receiver, SLOT(someSlot(int)));
```

But when I try run it, I get :

> NameError: global name 'MoveComplete' is not defined.

I've also tried running it like this

```
self.connect(self, QtCore.SIGNAL('MoveComplete(int)'), self, QtCore.SLOT(self.test2()))
```

But it gets called at the beginning of a function which performs a Movement and not after it has been completed.

How do I connect a slot to this signal?

Answer (score 0):

I obviously can't test this, and I don't know what documentation you're referring to, but something like this should work in PyQt4:

```
self.connect(axwidget, QtCore.SIGNAL('MoveComplete(int)'), self.test2)
```

That is, the first argument is an instance of your `QAxWidget` class, the second argument is the signal signature, and the last argument is a python callable object (i.e. a function, method, lambda, etc).

Connecting signals in PyQt doesn't always work in the same way as it does in C++. For more details, see [Old-style Signal and Slot Support](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/old_style_signals_slots.html) in the PyQt4 docs. The [New-style Signal and Slot Support](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html) is much more pythonic (and a lot less error-prone) - but I don't know whether it would work with ActiveX controls.